# why this loading gif layout issue

Tags: asp.net, html, css, ajax, cross-browser

CSS :

```
.smallLoaderBackground
{
    background-image: url('loaderBackground.gif') !important;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    z-index: 500;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML :

```
<asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upForm">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="smallLoaderBackground">
            <img id="loaderGif" style="padding-top: 9px;" alt="Loader" src="Styles/please-wait.gif" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

For some strange reason, I get different results on diff browsers :

IE works perfectly :

[image]

Chrome looks terrible, it places it at the bottom of the page instead of centering it, and the background is missing :

[image]

Opera Mobile looks fine like IE. But safari on 3GS looks like a cross between ie and chrome, the gif is in the middle but has no background.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please show your actual HTML output, not your .NET source code.

Comment: Suggestion: develop in a more standards-compliant browser first, and **then** ensure that the site also works in IE.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, as others pointed out, in order to properly debug your code, you're going to have to give us more than just the .NET source code. In the future, if possible, make a mock-up example of your problem on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), it makes it easier to pinpoint your specific problems.

Second, you should develop your application/solution in a more standards-compliant browser. IE is known as the black sheep amongst browsers, and for good reason too.
Relying your design on how it looks in IE is a bad way to develop cross-browser solutions.

Thirdly, your overlay shouldn't be fixed unless you want it across the entire screen. The overlay should be absolute to the parent element. Also make sure you've added `position: relative;` for your parent elements, otherwise the absolute positioning will do you no good. I don't know why you have `vertical-align` in there too, but by the looks of it, you don't really know what the different properties are for. I refer you to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html) and [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) to help you with that.

So, to sum up: provide more relevant code, IE sucks, make it absolute positioned.

---

I won't leave you without a solution however, so here's an example of how I'd make a simple loader overlay. This was developed using Chrome and JSFiddle.

### [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qKBDF/) | Code

CSS

```css
.up-form-loader-container{
    display: none;
}

.up-form-loader-container,
.up-form-loader-overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.up-form-loader-container,
.up-form-loader-overlay,
.up-form-loader-img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.up-form-loader-overlay{
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.up-form-loader-img{
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #4d1228;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin-left: -32px; margin-top: -32px;
}

#container h1{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#container h2{
    font-size: 11px;
}

#container{
    /*Centering the container for display purposes*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin-top: -225px; margin-left: -145px;
    /*--------------------------------------------*/
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #51182d;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px #bfbfbf; -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px #bfbfbf; -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px #bfbfbf;
    border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

.group{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 22px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #a3bccc;
    padding: 12px 8px 4px 8px;
}

.first-group{
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.group-title{
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    left: 6px;
    top: -12px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #4d1228;
    border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}

.group-submit{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
}

#email-adr{
    width: 100%;
}

#req-submit{
    padding: 2px 12px;
}

#cancel-submit, #cancel-submit:visited{
    color: darkblue;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#cancel-submit:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="up-form-loader-container">
        <div class="up-form-loader-overlay"></div>
        <img class="up-form-loader-img" src="http://www.newmoney.gov/WorkArea/images/application/loading_big.gif" width="64" height="64" />
    </div>
    <h2>ShadowCorp<sup>®</sup> Delivery on demand</h2>
    <h1>Price listing request</h1>
    <div class="first-group group">
        <div class="group-title">Items</div>
        <ul class="group-list">
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> Rubber mounting</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> Bellows</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> Rings</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> Hoses and boot</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> Filters</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> Gaskets</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> Mounts</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> Oil seals</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> TVD Dampers</label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group-title">Additional information</div>
        <ul class="group-horiz-list">
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> Bracket costs</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" /> X-ref</label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <div class="group-title"><label for="email-adr">E-mail address</label></div>
        <input type="textbox" id='email-adr'/></label>
    </div>
    <div class="group-submit">
        <input id="req-submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
        <a href="#cancel" id="cancel-submit">cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:
[image: Browser comparison]

Comment: Its going to take me some time to absorb your answer. It looks good, but I don't know how you got some of the info... i.e. that it was a price file generation form... and had an email address at the bottom etc.

Comment: @MuhammadA I extrapolated the information from your images. I am experienced enough to know what you were doing. :)